# How to export CMake settings (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) to other packages?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to add a `.cmake` file to my project which contains many multiple catkin projects.  Normally with cmake the way I would do this is set the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH variable to point to a cmake directory and then I could use the cmake command `include` to include a script from that directory.  Is there a good way to go about doing that in a catkin project so that other catkin projects that depend on my project could also use this cmake script?

The context is I am trying to find the right way to go about adding a `.cmake` file to a project like `moveit` which contains many different catkin projects and I'd like to only add my file in one place and ideally have it affect all the dependent catkin projects.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336670/how-to-export-cmake-settings-(cmake_module_path)-to-other-packages?/) by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2019-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this with a *CFG_EXTRAS file* (which is essentially a snippet of CMake) and exporting the location to it in your `catkin_package(.. CFG_EXTRAS ..)` call in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the package from which you'd like to export this.

See #q173947 for a Q&A where this is done for exporting compiler flags from a package, and #q93266 for an example where this is used to export a non-standard include path.

You should be able to append to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in the same way, as the extras-file contains just regular CMake. Be sure to specify the correct path to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`: it would need to be a path relative to the package that you're calling `catkin_package(.. CFG_EXTRAS ..)` in and also make sure to `install(..)` the extras-file as otherwise consumers of your package will not be able to find it when using an [install space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Install_Space).

As the paths to your package may be different in the `devel` and `install` space, you may have to use some templating to get the correct paths generated for you. `gencpp` does something similar (from [here](https://github.com/ros/gencpp/blob/e12443e0b6ab29f51eb361149e87e82bebfa4d93/cmake/gencpp-extras.cmake.em#L1-L9)):

```
@[if DEVELSPACE]@
  ...
@[else]@
  ...
@[end if]@
```

See also the [catkin documentation: Extracted CMake API reference](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-package) for more information on this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-02**:
And a final comment: while this can certainly be a valid approach to export certain information from CMake packages (it's essentially just CMake), be aware that it's easy to "overdo" this. That could result in creating tightly-coupled packages, which would be undesirable.